# controle file via SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I want to load an XML file and I have many conditions to apply to my file.

These are the columns in the XML:

[image]

`prop` and `text` are key-value pairs, and I need to check the values of particular keys to see if they meet my conditions.

This is an example of some of the key-value pairs from the XML file:

[image]

I load `prop` and `text` in SSIS, and then I want to check some conditions to determine where to route the file.

For example if `ID_PROGRAMME` is NULL, I have to send my XML file in SSIS to the rejection table.

In SSIS I have a control XML file and apply my conditions, but SSIS doesn't know 
the content of the `prop` and `text` column.

How can I do this operation please?

Comment: Sounds like you need a Conditional Split tool.

Comment: Conditional split

Comment: Check the following articles: [SSIS Conditional Split Transformation overview](https://www.sqlshack.com/ssis-conditional-split-transform-overview/), [SSIS Conditional Split overview](https://www.sqlshack.com/ssis-conditional-split-overview/)